# Group by a range of value with datatable using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a data table populated with values as follow:

```
Volume | Count
  100  |    2
  115  |    3
  165  |    1
  200  |    10
```

And I have a list of ranges contains values like: {50, 100, 150, 200}
I would like to count the by volume range like: from 50 - 100, 100 - 150. So I would expect result like:

```
Volume  | Count
50-100  |   2
100-150 |   5
150-200 |   11
```

This is what I've done:

```
Dim tmpDt as New DataTable
Dim tmpDt = New DataTable()
tmpDt.Columns.Add("Volume")
tmpDt.Columns.Add("Count")

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = tmpDt.NewRow
    dr("Volume") = 100
    dr("Count") = 2
    tmpDt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = tmpDt.NewRow
    dr("Volume") = 115
    dr("Count") = 3
    tmpDt.Rows.Add(dr)


    dr = tmpDt.NewRow
    dr("Volume") = 165
    dr("Count") = 1
    tmpDt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = tmpDt.NewRow
    dr("Volume") = 200
    dr("Count") = 10
    tmpDt.Rows.Add(dr)
Dim ranges As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer) From {50, 100, 150, 200}
Dim result = ranges.Select(Function(r) New With {Key.Volume = r, .Count = tmpDt.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("Volume") >= r).Count()})
```

The result from linq gives correct counting but not in ranges as I expected.
The result I got is below which is not what I want

```
Volume  | Count
50      |   16
100     |   16
150     |   11
```

I am wondering if this is possible using Linq?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. As far i understand you want to get count for each range of values. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are. Do you have any tips on it?

Comment: If a volume is on a border (like 100) you count the `count` twice - e.g. in the range 50-100 and 100-150. A range definition like "lower bound" <= x < "upper bound" seems to be better suited.

Comment: Hey guys, I figured out: Here is the query: Dim result = ranges.Select(Function(r) New With {Key .ADTVolume = r, _
                                                             .Count = tmpDt.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("ADTVolume") >= r _
                                                And x.Field(Of Decimal)("ADTVolume") <= ranges.Where(Function(r2) r2 > r).FirstOrDefault).Count()})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is a full query that display range and counting:

```
Dim result = ranges.Select(Function(r) New With {Key .ADTVolume = r, _ .Count = tmpDt.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("ADTVolume") >= r _ And x.Field(Of Decimal)("ADTVolume") <= ranges.Where(Function(r2) r2 > r).FirstOrDefault).Count()})
```